# Django uploading files history for user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

*I am able to upload the files in django. I have also managed to register different users. But when the users log in , they all see the set of files that were uploaded by anyone. instead I want the user views only those set of files which he/she has uploaded.*

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Document(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.CharField(max_length=255, )
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
def fileupload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        document = Document(
        description=request.POST['description'],
        document=myfile.name, 
        uploaded_at=datetime.datetime.now(),)
        document.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Member was created successfully!')
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return redirect('fileupload')
    else:
        documents = Document.objects.order_by('-uploaded_at')[:3]
        context = {'documents': documents}
    return render(request, 'fileupload.html', context)
```

Comment: Please see how to ask questions on stackoverflow and request you to post your models and views.

Comment: Added models.py and views.py files

Comment: There should be a relationship between the User model and the Document model.

Comment: OperationalError at /admin/checker/document/
no such column: checker_document.user_id  i get this error if i add the relationship between the user model and document model

Comment: add `user = models.ForeignKey(User)` to the `Document` model. If it gives an error then you should `import` the default `User` model at the top of your `models.py` (`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`).

Comment: OperationalError at /admin/checker/document/ no such column: checker_document.user_id .....Getting this error

Comment: you need to run migrations and sync your database, because the `user` column doesn't exist in your database.

Comment: python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb i did it still getting the same error

Comment: did you see if the migrations actually applied to the database? have you done makemigrations first? because this error says that the `user` column isn't in the `Document` table.

Comment: first i did python manage.py makemigrations appname then python manage.py migrate appname

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168393/discussion-between-syed-ali-and-king-reload).

Comment: when I did `migrate --run-syncdb` I remember that columns won't be applied to the database if you use sqlite database. So make sure that the column is actually there. Can you check in your database with maybe sqliteadmin if you have an sqlite database? if you have postgres, you need to do makemigrations first